# Calculating from GPS time duration of a linestringM within a polygon

Tags: postgis, gps, intersection, linestring, timestamp

I am analyzing trajectories from GPS points, including timestamp (Linestring M).
I need to clip trajectories that cross polygons, and calculate time spent within those polygons.

However, I have 2 issues :

- ST_Intersection allows me extracting only a Linestring, so that I loose the timestamp data and cannot calculate duration
- Even if ST_Intersection would keep M-value info, there is no certitude that nodes (points with timestamp from linestring) fall into the polygon.
  Meaning, PostGIS calculate "fake" nodes at the intersection between the trajectory and the polygon, that have no timestamp info.

Is there a way to calculate time spent into the polygon, whatever there is points inside or not (e.g. points on both sides)?

Comment: Maybe you could edit also the title to match your two questions because it is documented that ST_Intersects drops the M coordinates. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html.

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summarise duration of points within polygon using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362537/summarise-duration-of-points-within-polygon-using-postgis)

Comment: Another solution for paths zigzagging across the polygon: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429806/postgis-st-intersection-with-interpolated-m-value

Comment: I tried using the ST_InterpolatePoint as mentionned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362537/summarise-duration-of-points-within-polygon-using-postgis, but it produces sometimes negative sum of time duration, or unexpected differences in duration (calculated by hand through a GIS).